# Являются ли значения в enum class constexpr?

Tags: c++

Если при объявлении `enum class` (или просто `enum`) задать переменным значения через какие-то действия (сложение, вычитание и тд.), то будут ли они вычислены один раз на этапе компиляции?

```
enum class Foo {
  a = 20,
  b = a * 20,
  c = b + 1
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да.

Похоже, что если где-то можно использовать только constexpr выражение (а это легко проверить экспериментально), то это выражение всегда вычисляется на этапе компиляции.

Для сравнения, вызов constexpr-функции, если результат не требуется во время компиляции, запросто может быть выполнен в рантайме, если оптимизации выключены.

Но, конечно, стандарт тут ничего не гарантирует, и формально компиляторы могут делать что угодно, потому что понять по поведению программы разницу никак нельзя ([as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if)). Но все компиляторы, которые я проверил, ведут себя так, как я написал выше.